# Trouble accessing Nextcloud docker on local server with reverse proxy behind a pi hole DNS

Tags: docker, docker-compose, server, reverse-proxy, nextcloud

This is my first adventure into a self run server and I am at wits end trying to get Nextcloud docker set up on a local Ubuntu server.

First let me link a few resources I have pulled from:

https://www.ionos.com/digitalguide/server/configuration/nextcloud-installation-with-docker/

https://blog.ssdnodes.com/blog/installing-nextcloud-docker/

https://hub.docker.com/_/nextcloud

https://github.com/nextcloud/docker/tree/master/.examples

Goals:

1. Run Nextcloud docker and gitlab docker on a local Ubuntu server accessible while on my local network.
2. Each docker image (nextcloud and gitlab) needs to store data on a different drive from the OS dedicated to that service (ex 1TB hard drive for nextcloud image running on a 128gb drive).
3. Each service should be accessible via a subdomain ie cloud.mydomain.com and git.mydomain.com.
4. Each service should have encrypted communication channels (https).

Infrastructure:

1. 128GB OS drive for Docker images
2. 2 extra drives for each service (nextcloud, gitlab) which holds the docker-compose.yaml config files.
3. Local Pi Hole DNS where my domain (right now cloud.mydomain.com -> xxx.xxx.x.xx IP) is pointing to the Ubuntu server IP

Challenge:

Focusing solely on Nextcloud first:

I have gone through the Ionos, SSDnodes, and apache/fpm example docker-compose set ups and have not been able to access Nextcloud from my cloud.mydomain.com domain. When/if I can access a UI on cloud.mydomain.com it uses http without encryption and either has a server error or doesn't show up (DNS resolution error). Based on the logs it looks like there may be missing config files or insufficient permissions (or in one case too permissive drive permissions, go figure). When I try to access cloud.mydomain.com with https I get a certificate error where the certificate cannot be verified and IF I can force my browser to ignore it I get an nginx 500 error.

Possible pain points:

1. Drive Permissions.
2. I misconfigured my DNS.
3. I set up VIRTUAL_HOST wrong in the docker-compose file
4. PEBCAK

Any help anyone can provide will be greatly appreciated. I am really struggling to get this working and I am out of ideas. Let me know if anyone needs any additional information. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Okay after much fiddling I figured it out. Here is the solution:

1. Either ionos or ssdnode guide works just fine. The official examples gave me issues though so I can't assess those.
2. Ionos and ssdnode both require a domain (In this case a Pi Hole as a DNS server pointing mydomain.com to the server IP address
3. In the Ionos and ssdnode guide if you are using an external drive to hold the data, the app folder generated in the Ionos and ssdnode guide needs to have enhanced permissions (chmod 775 or 777)
4. If (like me) you try a number of things to see what works, remember to use docker-compose down -v to flush the mariadb volume. My most recent issue was a preexisting DB from an earlier attempt to get Nextcloud working
5. Make sure during the first set up you have CAN_INSTALL in the app/config folder

So in Conclusion:

1. Set up Pi Hole (or another DNS) first to make sure you have a domain pointing to your server IP
2. Follow Ionos or ssdnode guide
3. run docker-compose up -d
4. Immediately run: docker kill $(docker ps -a | awk '{print $1}')
5. Run: docker-compose down -v
6. Run: chmod -R 777 app/
7. Run: touch ./app/config/CAN_INSTALL
8. Run: docker-compose up -d

This should get you up and running. Feel free to remove anything unnecessary in my "mini guide". Some of this workaround is probably superfluous.